# diff on strings, not lines

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, diff, uniq

I feel I should be able to do this in my sleep, but let's say I have two text files each of which has a single column of the names of apache modules in no particular order. One file has 46 unique (to        itself) strings. The other has 67 lines and 67 uniq (to the file) strings. There will be many strings in common.

I need to find the names of apache modules that are -not- in the shorter, first file but -are- in the second, longer file.

I want to do this by searching and comparing **strings**. Line number, order, or postition are completely irrellevant. I just want to know which modules listed only in the longer file need to be installed.

By default uniq, comm and diff want to work by lines, and line numbers.
I don't want a side-by-side comparison; I just want a list.

Comment: can you put small sample from all the files that are involved? and also the expected output?

Comment: Do you care if there are items in the shorter that don't appear in the longer file or is this not even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Break your strings into lines, sort and uniqify them, and use `comm` for the analysis. (See [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)).

I'm going to assume, to have an example, that you want to compare the `LoadModule` directives between two Apache config files.

file1:

```
...other stuff...
LoadModule foo modules/foo.so
LoadModule bar modules/bar.so
LoadModule baz modules/baz.so
...other stuff...
```

file2:

```
...other stuff...
LoadModule foo modules/foo.so
...other stuff...
```

So, to do this:

```
comm -2 -3 \
  <(gawk '/LoadModule/ { print $2 }' file1 | sort -u)
  <(gawk '/LoadModule/ { print $2 }' file2 | sort -u)
```

...will suppress any lines found in both or only in the shorter file, and give you the module names found in the third, yielding the following output:

```
bar
baz
```

For folks looking at this question with more interesting use cases in mind -- unfortunately, while GNU sort's `-z` flag can handle NUL delimiters (to allow comparison on strings containing newlines), `comm` cannot. However, you can write your own `comm` implementation in shell which supports NUL delimiters, such as the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<"$1" 4<"$2"

IFS='' read -u 4 -d ''; input_two="$REPLY"

while IFS='' read -u 3 -d '' ; do
    input_one="$REPLY"
    while [[ $input_two < $input_one ]] ; do
        IFS='' read -u 4 -d '' || exit 0
        input_two="$REPLY"
    done
    if [[ $input_two = "$input_one" ]] ; then
        printf '%s\0' "$input_two"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Both files are just lists of apache module files like so: mod_vhost_alias.so
mod_mem_cache.so
mod_status.so
mod_ext_filter.so
mod_authz_user.so
mod_rewrite.so
mod_imagemap.so
mod_cgi.so

Comment: @user189395 if that's the case, you can leave out the gawk bits, and just send the content directly through `sort -u`. If the files are space-separated, you might pipe them through `tr ' ' '\n'` before the `sort` to change that to line separation.

Answer (score 1):

I would run a little bash script like this (differ.bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
f1=$1; # longer file
f2=$2; # shorter file

for item in `cat $f1`
do
    match=0
    for other in `cat $f2`
    do
        if [ "$item" == "$other" ]
        then
            match=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $match != 1 ]
    then
        echo $item
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Run it like so:

```
$ ./differ.bash file1 file2
```

Basically, I am just setting up a double for loop with the longer file on the outer loop and the shorter file on the inner loop. That way each item in the longer list gets compared with the items in the shorter list. This allows us to find all the items that don't match something in the smaller list.

---

**Edit:** I have tried to address Charles' first comment with this updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
f1=$1; # longer file
f2=$2; # shorter file

while read item
do
    others=( "${others[@]}" "$item" )
done < $f2

while read item
do
    match=0
    for other in $others
    do
        if [ "$item" == "$other" ]
        then
            match=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $match != 1 ]
    then
        echo $item
    fi
done < $f1

exit 0
```

Comment: Use of bare `cat $f1` exposes the contents of the file to not just string splitting (which is probably wanted, in this case) but also wildcard expansion -- so if, for instance, there's an entry in the file `f*`, it will be replaced with the names of all files in the current directory starting with `f`. Probably not the behavior you want. Also, reading a file inside an inner loop instead of storing its contents in an array just once beforehand is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: ...and in addition to being `O(n*m)` complexity with high constant values, this approach requires that both lists be able to fit in memory at once; `comm` reads entries only one line at a time, and GNU sort can use temporary files to sort and merge inputs larger than available RAM.

Comment: Agreed, if OP is trying to compare files that are 1G+ each, then he may have some troubles. I didn't think it was necessary to account for this though since his files contain 46 and 67 items. If his files for comparison get exceedingly larger, he may need to find a different approach.

Comment: I think you want `for other in "${others[@]}"` if using it as an array. Also, you can append to arrays as `my_array+=( "new_item" )` in non-ancient versions of the shell.

Comment: ...also, since you're using bash, I'd consider `(( match != 1 ))` (the match context) or `[[ $match != 1 ]]` (string context, but as a shell keyword with no string-splitting on `$match`; otherwise you could get a syntax error if `$match` were empty). And `echo "$item"`, not `echo $item`, to avoid glob expansion on your variable`s contents.

Comment: ...btw, do initialize your arrays (`others=()` or `declare -a others`)

Comment: ergh. "math" context, not "match" context.